# View Question/Answer edits without refreshing page

Tags: feature-request, edits, notifications

You can view comments and new answers to a question without refreshing the page. Edits don't appear until the page is refreshed. There should really be a notification or something for edits, so if you have had the question open for some time, you can see the latest versions of all posts.

The reason for this is that sometimes I will comment about an error in someone's answer, after they have corrected it. That is pretty annoying, for me and for them.

Right now it seems there is no way to view an edited post without refreshing the page. Am I right?

Comment: I just suffered from this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10272932/quickest-array-initialization. Edited after the maker had, so everything was wrong.

Comment: I have recently seen an edit notification pop up. I seems to be pretty buggy, since I don't think the question was even edited, but it looks like they may be doing something about this.

Comment: Hopefully, but it is kind of slow

Comment: Okay, this seems to be implemented now, just as lunboks described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that this has been implemented recently, via the new WebSocket live update system.

When a post is edited while you have it open, you get a little notification bar at the top of it:

> an edit has been made to this post; click to load

Clicking that will load the most recent revision. This will work even if the edit didn't create a revision, i.e. if the OP edits the post within the grace period.

Comment: That sounds almost right. I have seen the notification, but it didn't seem to work. I didn't know there was a 'grace period' feature, either. And thanks for the link, I was apparently missing the same thing.